# Convert Observable<List<SomeObject>> to List<SomeObject>

Tags: rx-java

How do I convert:

```
Observable<List<SomeObject>> to List<SomeObject>
```

Using this this:

```
Observable.just(index)
            .map { d ->
                // returns an Observable<List<someObject>>
            }
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map { r ->
                doSomething(r) // r must be converted to a List<someObject>
            }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .take(1)
            .subscribe {
            }
```

Comment: The `map` operator applies a transformation to each one of the stream's values, so if the observable where `map` is used is of type `Observable<Thing>`, it's logic will be applied to values of type `Thing`. From what I can tell, you're returning an `Observable<List<SomeObject>>` from the first 'map', i.e., transfrorming `d` into an `Observable<List<SomeObject>>`. That means that you're applying your second `map` to an `Observable<Observable<List<SomeObject>>>`. Did I understand your example correctly?

Comment: The first map is returning a Observable<List<someObject>>. In the second map, I want to call doSomething with just List<someObject>. The doSomething function expects List<someObject> and not Observable<List<someObject>>

Comment: Inside your first map's scope, are you explicitly returning something of type `List<Object>` or `Observable<List<Object>>`? If it's the latter, you should consider using a `flatMap`.

Comment: Ok that was correct. The first map should be a flatmap. I thought I understood flatMap. Apparently I don't. You can put your answer as a solution and I'll select it. Thanks!

Comment: Haha yeah, I've been there. RxJava has the ability to continuously knock you down when you're learning how to use it. Glad I helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're explicitly returning an `Observable<List<SomeObject>>` in your first `map`, you should instead use a `flatMap` to flatten the observables into one. Otherwise, your first `map` is actually returning an `Observable<Observable<List<SomeObject>>>`.